# Django ошибка при развертывании на хостинге

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Установил на сервер virtualenv-1.9.1 python 3.2.3 Django 1.8. Перекинул файлы сайта на сервер. Запустил python3 manage.py collectstatic и вылезла ошибка.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/c/cu95348/myenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/c/cu95348/myenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/c/cu95348/myenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/c/cu95348/myenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/c/cu95348/myenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/__init__.py", line 124, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 824, in _gcd_import
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name))
ImportError: No module named studsite`

При запуске на компьютере, а так-же при запуске на raspberry-pi и на pythonanywhere.com такой ошибки не было. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже интерпретатор питона не знает где искать пакет studsite. Это, видимо, ваше django-приложение, подключенное в настройках.
Убедитесь, что в настройках правильно указан путь к корню проекта.
Добавьте в sys.path путь к каталогу, где лежит папка studsite с вашим приложением.